# Why did McAlpine (M) sue under the main contract between M and Panatown, rather than under the duty of care deed between M and UIPL?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

[Richard](https://www.uclan.ac.uk/staff_profiles/richard-taylor.php) and [Damian](https://www.slaughterandmay.com/who-we-are/partners/damian-taylor/) Taylor. [*Contract Law Directions* (2019 7 ed)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/contract-law-directions-9780198836599?&lang=en&).   [BAILII](http://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKHL/2000/43.html) has *Alfred McAlpine Construction Limited v. Panatown Limited* [2000] UKHL 43. p 349.

> #### Benefits in construction contracts
>
> The House of Lords confirmed in the complex case of *Alfred McAlpine v Panatown* (2001) that,
>   outside the social/consumer contracts where the contract is made by one party for the benefit
>   of others as a matter of convenience and simplicity, there is no general rule allowing a contracting
>   party to recover a loss on behalf of a third party.
>
> McAlpine contracted with Panatown to construct a building on land owned by UIPL, a company
>   in the same group as Panatown. McAlpine also provided a ‘duty of care deed’ to UIPL directly
>   whereby they agreed to use all reasonable skill, etc. in constructing the building.

p 350

> The project did not go well and the costs of repairs for the alleged defects plus damages for
>   delay were estimated to be tens of millions of pounds. **The decision was made by the group of
>   companies to sue under the main contract between McAlpine and Panatown rather than under
>   the duty of care deed between McAlpine and UIPL. [I boldened.]** McAlpine argued that Panatown, as opposed
>   to UIPL who was the owner of the defective building, had suffered no loss. Panatown
>   argued in the House of Lords: (i) that it was entitled to recover the loss suffered by UIPL on its
>   behalf; and (ii) that in any event it had suffered a loss itself in that it had not received what it
>   bargained for even if it was itself financially no worse off.
>
> [image]
>
> On the first point relating to recovery of loss suffered by a third party, the House of Lords was
>   clear, as has already been said, that there was no general rule permitting such recovery. The real
>   issue here however was whether Panatown could rely on a special rule traceable back to *Dunlop
>   v Lambert* in 1839 and referred to in *The Albazero* (1977) by Lord Diplock in relation to contracts
>   for the carriage of goods. This rule was then developed by the House of Lords in *Linden Gardens
>   v Lenesta* (1994) so as to apply to contracts for the construction of a building.
>
> The *Dunlop v Lambert/Albazero* exception applies to contracts whereby the claimant is the
>   original consignor of goods to the defendant carrier, it being contemplated that the ownership
>   of the goods will be transferred on by the claimant to subsequent purchasers whilst still being
>   carried by the defendant. The subsequent purchasers are therefore the ones who are, by the
>   time of the breach, the owners who suffer the actual loss or damage to the goods but who have
>   no contract with the defendant carrier. The exception recognizes that the claimant can recover
>   damages even though he suffers no loss personally and that he holds the damages on behalf
>   of the subsequent purchasers who have suffered loss.
>
> This exception was applied by the House of Lords in *Linden Gardens v Lenesta* (1993), or more
>   accurately in the second case heard and reported with that case, *St Martin’s Property Corporation
>   v McAlpine*.

Comment: I need more context - don’t understand the party’s roles in the arrangement

Comment: @DaleM Thanks. I quoted more from the textbook. You see my link to BAILII right?

Answer (score 1):

Ewan McKendrick's [The Common Law at Work: The Saga of Alfred *McAlpine Construction Ltd v Panatown Ltd*](https://doi.org/10.1080/14729342.2003.11421428) answers your question at p. 151.

> The defects alleged to exist in the works presented the Unex Group with the
> need to make a decision. They had two principal potential means of redress. The
> first was for Panatown to sue McAlpine for breach of the building contract and the
> second was for UIPL to sue McAlpine for breach of the duty of care deed. Neither
> route was free from difficulty. With the benefit of hindsight, we can see that the
> most obvious difficulty with the first route lay in demonstrating that Panatown had
> suffered a loss as a result of McAlpine’s alleged breaches of contract.25 But in other
> respects, a contractual claim by Panatown appeared advantageous. In the first
> place, the contract contained an arbitration clause and so could be resolved before
> an arbitrator without McAlpine being able to join numerous subcontractors to the
> proceedings. Secondly, the rights contained in the contract were more extensive
> than those to be found in the duty of care deed: the contract contained a number
> of strict obligations and also made provision for the payment of liquidated damages
> for delay. Thirdly, Alfred McAlpine plc, the holding company of McAlpine,
> had entered into a parent company guarantee with Panatown under which it
> agreed to guarantee due performance of the contract by its subsidiary, McAlpine.

He didn't break a new para, but I do so to make reading easier.

> On the other hand, the advantage of a claim under the duty of care deed was that
> UIPL did not appear to have any difficulty in establishing that it had suffered a loss
> as a result of the alleged breaches of duty by McAlpine. But in other respects a
> claim under the duty of care deed was more hazardous. In particular, the duty of
> care deed did not contain an arbitration clause, the duty assumed by McAlpine
> under the deed was not strict but only to exercise reasonable care and skill and
> UIPL did not have the benefit of a parent company guarantee by Alfred McAlpine
> plc. Thus it was decided by the Unex group that Panatown should bring proceedings
> against McAlpine, invoking the arbitration clause contained in that contract.
> Notice of arbitration was given by Panatown on 8 July 1992, prior to the determination
> of the contract between Panatown and McAlpine.